# Plants: Aristotles vs. modern biology

Tags: reference-request, history-of-philosophy, aristotle

Corals, sea anemones, sponges, etc. are animals according to modern biology. Mold or mushrooms are not plants and belong to their own realm of fungi. The Venus flytrap is a plant, though it is capable of fast reaction – it seems to have tactile sensation in some sense. Microorganisms were unobservable to Aristotle and their presence could at best be inferred (brewing, fermentation), but they are not plants.

All this stands in conflict with Aristotle, who defined plants to be just capable of nourishment and growth. And animals to have sensation and movement on top of that.

Is there any mention of one of those species in Aristotle’s works, which modern biology classifies very differently?

Comment: Aristotle knew of mushrooms and fungi, he even discussed why some of them glow, they were classified as plants. "*Even though Aristotle probably did not know about carnivorous plants, such as sundews and venus flytraps, by pointing out the features he explains about these borderline cases, I will here argue that had he known about the carnivorous plants, he would have necessarily categorized them as animals, and not as plants*", see [Isseicreekphilosophy's Blog](https://isseicreekphilosophy.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/aristotles-conception-of-carnivorous-plants-as-animals/).

Comment: Might be of interest: [In Our Time, Aristotle's Biology - BBC Radio 4](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/m0002cfd)